# How to create a loop to use it as a filter of a query on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, loops, dbeaver

I've been searching out a way to create a loop that uses a series of dates as filter for a query, and insert its results on another table.

I tried to adapt some queries that I've found on other topics, but it didn't work out.

My thought was to create a loop based on a time period of months, which would replace the filters and the JOINs' keys. I need to do it separately since my table of origin contains two fields that need to be evaluated for each period.

I've tried to build what I believe would be the query to be used in the loop:

```
SELECT
      a.client_id 
    , COALESCE(b.batch,c.batch) batch
FROM
    table1 a
LEFT JOIN
    table2 b ON date_trunc('month',a.starts_at)::date = b.batch
LEFT JOIN
    table2 c ON date_trunc('month',a.ends_at)::date = c.batch
WHERE 
    date_trunc('month',a.received_at) >= b.batch - INTERVAL '1 month'
    AND date_trunc('month',a.received_at) < b.batch + INTERVAL '2 month'
    AND a.selection = 'GROUP 1'
    AND a.status = 'SUCCESS'
```

So every `batch` should be substituted to a truncated date on a month level (Example: from '2022-01-01' to '2022-12-01'). The objective is that this script runned one time for each month, inserting the results on another table.

Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. Could anyone help me figure out the best way to structure this script?

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Edit 1: as asked by Adrian, here are some specifications about the tables.

table1:

`client_id` - user identification (multiples rows for the same user)

`received_at` - timestamp which the register was added

`starts_at` - timestamp with the beggining of the validity

`ends_at` - timestamp with the ending of the validity

`selection` and `status` are both filters which will be applied.

table2:

Table that would contain the date range (`batch`) which will be used as filter to the loop. This could be changed if it doesn't work or isn't optimal.

Edit 2:

Hello, @AdrianKlaver!

I think the problem with using the range function on the filter is that I need to consider a register on a batch if either `starts_at` or `ends_at` timestamps is on it.

Example:

```
id |      starts_at      |       ends_at       
----+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | 03/16/2023 01:12:00 | 04/15/2023 14:17:00
```

This case should be considered on March and April batches. That's why I used the LEFT JOINs on both timestamps, and combined them on a `coalesce`.

Do you think we can adapt your suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Does `table2` have a field that matches `a.client_id`? 2) Add the tables definitions as text update to question.

Comment: Hello, Adrian! First of all, thanks for answering.

About your question: no. The `table2` doesn't have a `client_id` field. It would be an auxiliary table created to be used as a part of the loop. I've put more details on my original post. Thanks for pointing it out to add more details about them.

Comment: Use [Range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) types? As in: `select daterange('04/01/2023', '04/30/2023') @> daterange('04/06/2023', '04/16/2023')  t` per [Range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html). Where the first range is the `batch` and the second is the start/end dates for each id.

Comment: Hello, @AdrianKlaver! I've added more details on the original post for formatting reasons.

Comment: See **UPDATE** to answer.  Ranges are pretty useful and have [operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) that cover many situations.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, using the range contained operator `@>` where the operator determines whether the range on the right side is contained by the range on the left:

```
create table table1(id integer, starts_at timestamp, ends_at timestamp);

insert into table1 values 
  (1, '2023-04-01 01:12', '2023-04-19 14:17'), 
  (1, '2023-04-05 15:11', '2023-04-07 08:10'), 
  (2, '2023-04-11 16:45', '2023-04-25 02:30'), 
  (1, '2023-04-26 18:23', '2023-05-05 11:05');

select 
   id, starts_at, ends_at 
from 
   table1 
where 
   daterange('04/01/2023', '04/30/2023') @> daterange(starts_at::date, ends_at::date);
 id |      starts_at      |       ends_at       
----+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | 04/01/2023 01:12:00 | 04/19/2023 14:17:00
  1 | 04/05/2023 15:11:00 | 04/07/2023 08:10:00
  2 | 04/11/2023 16:45:00 | 04/25/2023 02:30:00
```

**UPDATE**

Change range operator to overlap test `&&` that checks whether the two ranges have overlapping dates.

```
insert into table1 values (2, '2023-05-12', '2023-05-28');

select 
   id, starts_at, ends_at 
from 
   table1 
where 
   daterange('04/01/2023', '04/30/2023') && daterange(starts_at::date, ends_at::date);
 id |      starts_at      |       ends_at       
----+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | 04/01/2023 01:12:00 | 04/19/2023 14:17:00
  1 | 04/05/2023 15:11:00 | 04/07/2023 08:10:00
  2 | 04/11/2023 16:45:00 | 04/25/2023 02:30:00
  1 | 04/26/2023 18:23:00 | 05/05/2023 11:05:00

select                                                    
   id, starts_at, ends_at 
from 
   table1 
where 
   daterange('05/01/2023', '05/31/2023') && daterange(starts_at::date, ends_at::date);
 id |      starts_at      |       ends_at       
----+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | 04/26/2023 18:23:00 | 05/05/2023 11:05:00
  2 | 05/12/2023 00:00:00 | 05/28/2023 00:00:00
```